# How broadcast data of HTTP post method in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm using the same HTTP method in different controller like following sample:

**Service:**

```
var method="sampleMethod"
    HotalStatisticService.GetReservations = function (data) {
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            url:'http://sample.com/'+method
        });
    }
```

**first controller**

```
.controller("SampleACtrl", function ($scope,HotalStatisticService ) {
    HotalStatisticService.GetReservations({start:start, end:end, type:type})
        .success(function (data) {
         $scope.sampleA=data;
        })
}
```

**second controller**

```
.controller("SampleBCtrl", function ($scope,HotalStatisticService ) {
    HotalStatisticService.GetReservations({start:start, end:end, type:type})
            .success(function (data) {
             $scope.sampleB=data;
            })
    }
```

How do I use here method in the only one controller?

Comment: I'm sorry, could you clarify exactly what you want?

Comment: how can i transfer data between different controllers for example broadcast,emit

Comment: The two controllers are in two different modules?

Comment: two controller has only one module

Comment: Try pushing in a $rootScope reference in both of them?

Comment: Do you want to reuse the same logic?

Comment: Something like this ?[link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Tsl3iScx2BMHgfxSWuow?p=preview)

Comment: maybe ,i will try this logic in  the code

Comment: Let me know, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Let me say that the other solution that uses factories is probably a MUCH better solution.Using Services is also a good option.*

Another ,perhaps crude way to do it is using $rootScope.Answer below.

What you essentially want to do is share data between the two controllers. Based on your reply from the comments, both the controllers belong to the same module.You can use `$rootScope` here to act as a common point.

As you can see, i've added `$rootScope` as a dependency in both the controllers and simply printed the `txt` variable in the second div.

**JS Code**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('ACtrl', function($scope,$rootScope) {
  $scope.name = 'This is Controller A ';
  $scope.execute = function() {
    alert('Executed!');
  }
  $rootScope.txt="Hi there from the other side";
});

app.controller('BCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope) {
  $scope.name = 'This is Controller B ';

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="ACtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

  </div>


  <div ng-controller="BCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    {{txt}}
  </div>
```

Here is the **[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Tsl3iScx2BMHgfxSWuow?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is create a [factory service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#factory) that handles your HTTP requests, and then inject that service into your controllers...  Code would look something like this:

var app = angular.module('sampleApp');

```
app.factory('sampleFactory', ['$http',
    function($http) {

        return {
            getData: function(success, fail) {
                if (_dataStore) {
                    success(_dataStore);
                }

                $http({
                    //fill in your params here
                }) 
                .then(
                function successCallback(response) {
                    //store data in the _dataStore object
                    success(response)
                }, fail(response))
            },

            _dataStore: {}
        }
    }
]);

app.controller('SampleACtrl', ['$scope', 'sampleFactory',
    function($scope, sampleFactory) {
        $scope.sampleA = sampleFactory.getData(success, fail);
    }
]);

app.controller('SampleBCtrl', ['$scope', 'sampleFactory',
    function($scope, sampleFactory) {
        $scope.sampleB = sampleFactory.getData(success, fail);
    }
]);
```

The main idea behind doing it like this is that you only make the HTTP request once, and then store the data in the factory as an object.  When you call the getData() function on that object, you'll either get what is actually in the factory already (meaning the request was already made) or you'll go make the request.  You'd pass in 2 functions (success or fail) as your response functions to the $http call.  This is by far not 100% good, there's many improvements(add $q in there to return promises, etc) but it's a start in the right direction.
**Long story short: USE FACTORIES!**